# tensor product is finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $P$ be a $A$-$B$ bimodule which is finitely generated as a left $A$ module. Take $Q$ a $B$-$C$ bimodule that is finitely generated as a left $B$-module. Then show that $P\otimes_BQ$ is finitely generated as a left $A$-module.

I suppose the "base" of $P\otimes_BQ$ is the set $\{p_i\otimes q_i\}$ where the $p_i$ generate $P$ and the $q_i$ generate $Q$. However, I can't show that this is true.

$p\otimes q = \sum((a_ip_i)\otimes (b_jq_j))$ but there is no way of combining $q_j$ and $p_i$ to get an element in $A$.

I suspect that the exercise is not correctly stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element of $P\otimes_BQ$ is a finite sum of elements of the form $x\otimes y$, with $x\in P$ and $y\in Q$.

Now, with your notation,
$$
y=\sum_{j=1}^n b_jq_j
$$
so that
$$
x\otimes y=\sum_{j=1}^n xb_j\otimes q_j
$$
Since $xb_j$ is a (finite) linear combination of $p_1,\dots,p_m$ with coefficients in $A$, we're done.